# Bus route scheme of Dubrovnik

Tags: public-transport, buses, routes, dubrovnik

I am trying to determine how to get around Dubrovnik by public transport. Specifically, I am interested in a bus route that goes from the Hotel Ivka to the Old City centre.

From what I gathered from the city bus company [Libertas](http://libertasdubrovnik.com/home-english/), the closest to what I am looking for is probably the bus no. 6, since it goes from Babin Kuk to Pile. However, the Hotel Ivka is not listed anywhere near a bus stop name on the timetable ([pdf](http://libertasdubrovnik.com/wp-content/uploads/linija-6.pdf)) for this bus. The [hotel's website](http://hotel-ivka.com/location) is similarly unhelpful as it only says

> Bus stop is close to the hotel with very good and frequent connection to the Old Town.

Neither Google maps nor HERE WeGo have any information on public transport on Dubrovnik.

**What would be the best way to get from Lapad** (Hotel Ivka) **to the Old City?**

More generally: **is there a bus route map available for Dubrovnik?**

Comment: Have you tried contacting the hotel? Will it be sufficient to ask once you arrive there? Good question otherwise and +1 for showing that you have done previous research :) Welcome to Travel SE!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenStreetMap hivemind](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/42.65318/18.08005) thinks that bus no.6 stops at Igralište station not far from Ivka.

And, actually, the PDF with timetable explicitly say so.

Comment: You were right, I must have missed that in the pdf. Your link was useful in any case, however, as it provided the right location of the bus stop. Thank you!